# Waterfall ggplot - total column doesn't get formatting

Tags: ggplot2, formatting

Using the waterfalls package.
Formatting doesn't seem to apply to Total column.

Here's the data:

| Factors | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Start | 119.19 |
| Differential A | -25.4 |
| Move | -0.832 |
| EQ | -5.70 |
| Differential (Premium) | 4.93 |
| Transportation | -7.37 |

I can get a plot with this:

```
waterfall(wf, calc_total=TRUE, rect_width=.4, fill_by_sign=TRUE, total_rect_color="grey", rect_border=NA) + labs(y="Cost", title ="Waterfall", x=NULL)
```

![Result 1] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmJFc.png)

Why doesn't rect_border=NA apply to the Total column?
And why doesn't the y-axis label show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the total bar requires its own formatting.
To remove border:

```
total_rect_border_color=NA
```

I just applied a different theme to get the Y-axis label to show up, ie. theme_minimal()

```
wf %>%
    mutate(Factors = str_wrap(Factors, width = 10)) %>%
    waterfall(calc_total=TRUE, rect_width=.4, fill_by_sign=TRUE, total_rect_color="darkgreen", rect_border=NA, total_rect_border_color = NA, rect_text_labels=scales::dollar_format()(wf$Cost), total_rect_text = scales::dollar_format()(sum(wf$Cost))) + 
    labs(y="Cost", title ="Waterfall", x=NULL) + theme_minimal()
```

[image: Chart with y-axis labelled and no border on Total bar]